# how to query kms encrypted data in redshift

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift, amazon-kms

I have encrypted my s3 keys with aws kms and pushed to redshift via copy command.  The encrypted file contains ciphertextblob and key fields.  Is there a way we can query the real data that is encrypted already?

The real data is like this

```
{"id":"1","name":"dummyname",age:"42"}
```

My encrypted data looks like this

```
{"CiphertextBlob":[1,2,3,0,120,233,75,200,66,143,164,147,227,238,147,160,116,177,169,157,151,230,181,14,191,156,140,146,43,184,202,30,55,51,17,114,237,1,96,101,196,239,48,167,210,15,193,102,57,210,110,143,138,232,0,0,0,126,48,124,6,9,42,134,72,134,247,13,1,7,6,160,111,48,109,2,1,0,48,104,6,9,42,134,72,134,247,13,1,7,1,48,30,6,9,96,134,72,1,101,3,4,1,46,48,17,4,12,14,218,49,42,14,25,206,72,238,21,16,108,2,1,16,128,59,185,185,70,8,156,85,194,144,17,206,233,181,87,105,10,140,135,145,66,47,247,242,163,1,69,237,116,152,162,95,86,73,209,218,214,205,204,214,243,151,78,99,3,19,56,105,58,202,158,36,227,244,108,99,93,209,4,50,113],"Plaintext":[243,146,203,144,109,46,20,207,245,11,58,63,178,191,136,49,243,247,189,88,11,28,59,222,217,53,156,239,233,15,129,22],"KeyId":"arn:aws:kms:<region>:<id>:key/<key>"}
```

When this is pushed to redshift via copy command, are there any ways AWS decrypt data by default and allows querying the real data?

Comment: [Encrypt Your Amazon Redshift Loads with Amazon S3 and AWS KMS](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/encrypt-your-amazon-redshift-loads-with-amazon-s3-and-aws-kms/)?

Comment: Thanks. The above link talks about encryption and loading to redshift.  What about querying redshift after encryption?

Comment: Could you please Edit your question and provide more information? For example, how was the data encrypted -- did you use Amazon S3 SSE-KMS automatic encryption, or did you encrypt it yourself? If you did it yourself, was there any particular reason for doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**AWS KMS Encyprtion for Redshift**

If you did S3 encryption or Client side encryption(AWS CLI) using AWS KMS keys,
and pushed data to Redshift using copy command ,you can query the data as the data will be in decrypted format in the Redshift Database.

Only during the loading,your data will be encrypted format and Redshift uses AWS KMS keys to decrypt the pushed data to Redshift.